# Querying data in mongoDB using Compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

im new to mongoDb and despite querying i cannot successfully get the data I need using compass.

My document looks like this:
[image: dreaded screenshot]

I want to see all candidates  who are in the folder Pending. Candidates is an array and has roughly 200 objects within it.

Regards

Comment: I added a sample query, if you post the exact result you are expecting, I can adjust the query

Answer (score 1):

try this:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/dmH6F5aiRXR

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      "path": "$candidates"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "candidates.details.folder": {
        $eq: "PENDING"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      "newRoot": "$candidates"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Do you need to `$unwind` and then `$match`?

Comment: Thanks for noticing that, I updated to switch the order of $unwind then $match